# ng-model preventing ng-value to be displayed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ejs

I'm pretty new to angular world and I have an issue with it.
I'm working with ejs too.

I have an input that I want to fill (value) with an ng-model.
The problem is my model is empty while the user doesn't specify a value.
I want to display a default value when my model is empty. This default value is sending by the ejs (server side). Doing that, I can't set a default value in my controller.

To do so I wrote the following :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="owner_adress" ng-value="'{{owner_adress || '<%=user.owner_adress%>'}}'"/>
```

If I look into my code, I can see the value is okay (ejs result when my model is empty, my model value otherwise) but the value is not displayed in my input (ie the user can't see it).

I looked for a work around (ng-cloak was fine but I can't use it in my input field).
Any clue would be nice !

Comment: Don't try to store data in a template at server-side. A template should be just that: a template. Consider it as purely static. The single point of truth for data is the model. And the model should be populated from JSON responses to $http requests.

Comment: I don't really want to store datas in my template since I have to get the model value in my controller after my form is filled by the user.
In your opinion I have to populate my model in my controller with the default value returned by the ejs ?

Comment: You don't really want to do it, but you *are* doing it with `<%=user.owner_adress%>`. Your controller should instead call a REST service of the backend which would return the data, as JSON, to display in the view. Note that the templates are cached by Angular. So if you change the user address on the server and go back to this page, it will still display the old user address, since you hard-coded it in the template. I repeat: data has nothing to do in the template.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I get your point. The user variable is the user informations which are returned by the server each time a page is loaded ( res.render('partials/account', {user: user}); in my nodejs server) in JSON. I don't want to call a service after the page is loaded.

Comment: You're using AngularJS. AngularJS doesn't load **pages** as traditional web applications do. It loads html **templates** and caches them. Those templates are then populated with data and displayed. If you navigate elsewhere in the angular app and then go back to a page using the same template, angular will get the template from its cache. It won't ask your web server for the template again. Why? because templates should be templates. They should not contain data like a user address. data should be loaded by the controller using $http, when needed.

Comment: I think I get it. Last question (thank you for your time): since **all** my routing pass through my nodejs server, if I update my database with my form value and my "user" too, the template will remain the same ?

(node server -> user.data -> template form -> user fill the form -> submit -> node server -> update database -> redirect in template form) Is the template remain the same ?

Comment: As I said: angularJS load a template once, and then keeps it in cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) directive instead. If `owner_adress` is defined in controller it will be used, otherwise it will default to serverside rendered value:

```html
<input ng-model="owner_adress" type="text"
       ng-init="owner_adress = owner_adress || '<%=user.owner_adress%>'"/>
```